# Materializecss horizontal form

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, materialize

I'm trying to make the informative form on a materializecss when I inculde Materializecss it looks like this:

[image]

https://www.bootply.com/dpVsPm6vsI

Example without Materializecss:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Bootstrap Horizontal Form</h2>
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Yyyyy Yyy:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <label class="control-label" id="email">Yyy Value</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Xxxxxx XXxx:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <label class="control-label" id="email">Xxxxxx Value</label>
      </div>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>


<div id="push"></div>
```

Example with Materializecss:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/css/materialize.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Bootstrap Horizontal Form</h2>
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Yyyyy Yyy:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <label class="control-label" id="email">Yyy Value</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Xxxxxx XXxx:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <label class="control-label" id="email">Xxxxxx Value</label>
      </div>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>


<div id="push"></div>
```

Comment: The real problem here is that as soon as you include materializecss it messes up the layout. Could you make that clear in the question?

Comment: I want to do this using materializecss: https://www.bootply.com/dpVsPm6vsI

But i didn't. I made: https://jsfiddle.net/evolving/7pjLgrn2/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all. I did: https://jsfiddle.net/evolving/7pjLgrn2/18/ 
`<label>` to `<p>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container">
<h2>Bootstrap Horizontal Form</h2>
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Yyyyy Yyy:</label>
        <label class="control-label" id="email">Yyy Value</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="email">Xxxxxx XXxx:</label>
        <label class="control-label" id="email">Xxxxxx Value</label>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I want to use materaliazecss.

Comment: i did not get you?

Comment: @Programmer21 The real problem here is that as soon as the OP includes materializecss it messes up the layout.